# Trigger to see if a table is updated

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

To start off, I'm not a DB guy. Just in a learning phase of it. Let's consider a table named **`Accounts`**. It has four columns as mentioned below.

```
---------------------------------------------
|  PK  |   AcType  |  FName | LName |  Zip  |
---------------------------------------------
|   1  |  Savings  |  AAA   |  ZZZ  | 11111 |
|   2  |  Checking |  BBB   |  YYY  | 22222 |
|   3  |  Checking |  CCC   |  XXX  | 33333 |
---------------------------------------------
```

How do we determine if a value is changed in the table?
(It may be a single change or multiple changes)

For ex:

```
---------------------------------------------
|  PK  |   AcType  |  FName | LName |  Zip  |
---------------------------------------------
|   1  |  Savings  |  AAA   |  ZZZ  | 11111 |
|   2  |  Savings  |  BBB   |  YYY  | 22222 |
|   3  |  Checking |  CCC   |  XXX  | 33333 |
---------------------------------------------
```

We can see that data is changed in **`AcType`** of second row to **`Savings`**.

How do we implement a trigger to determine if there is a change (either of `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`) in any of the fields of the table?

Comment: Make a trigger on update is one thing but what is the action your trigger is supposing to do ?

Comment: @ThomasG Trigger is supposed to determine if the table is changed.

Comment: The table change is the action that will trigger the trigger. But that trigger has to do something when it triggers, like write the information in a table...

Comment: @ThomasG Oops! So in that case, can it be written in such a way that it stores a value TRUE if table is changed? (Stored in a new table, say Status with column names as TimeStamp and ChangeStatus - where it stores time at which the table is changed and a value TRUE in the column ChangeStatus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER AccountsChanged
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON Accounts
BEGIN
    insert into change_log_table(change_time, what_changed, change_status) values (sysdate, 'Accounts', 'TRUE')
END;
```

You can also recognize action

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER AccountsChanged
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON Accounts
    DECLARE
    action_type varchar2(1);
    BEGIN
      if inserting then action_type := 'I' end if;
      if updating then action_type := 'U' end if;
      if deleting then action_type := 'D' end if;
      insert into change_log_table(change_time, what_changed, change_status, action_type) 
             values (sysdate, 'Accounts', 'TRUE', action_type)
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you did really mean it like you need to know any change of the table, you can do this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER AccountsChanged
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON Accounts
BEGIN
    doWhatEverYouNeed;
END;
```

where doWhatEverYouNeed is your procedure taking an action after the table is modified

however it will trigger also on any update, even if the values wouldn't change
if you need to trigger only when some value is changed, you need to use something like this:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER AccountsChanged
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON Accounts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if updating 
    then
        IF :NEW.AcType <> :OLD.AcType or :NEW.FName <> :OLD.FName or :NEW.LName <> :OLD.LName or :NEW.Zip <> :OLD.Zip
        then
            doWhatEverYouNeed;
        end if;
    else
        doWhatEverYouNeed;
    end if;

END;
```